# Why jQuery cached variable is not seen in an outer function?

Tags: jquery

I am just curious why this code is not working.

I can't see the `$note` variable in the `hey()` function

```
function hey(kc) {
$note.html(kc);
 }

$(function () {

 var $note = $('#note');    
 hey("Joice");

 });
```

A fiddle to play with
http://jsfiddle.net/VcdxB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it's a matter of [scope](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/). This is my pattern for caching jQuery objects:

```
// global scope
// single hash to hold all reference to cached jQuery objects
var $jq = {};

$(function() {

   $jq.note = $('#note'); 
   $jq.name = $('#name'); 

});

function hey(kc) {
    $jq.note.html(kc);
}
```

Comment: I wish if I can mark all the answers as "right", but I liked yours more since it's more elegant to collect all jQuery cached variables in a one object :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the var keyword inside a function, you declare a local variable only visible inside the function scope (the function itself and other functions inside).

Comment: for more info about scope in JavaScript: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/ , see my answer below for my personal jQuery caching pattern

Answer (score 1):

Because it is **local** to the function bound to the `ready` event.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VcdxB/1/

```
function hey(kc) {
    $note.html(kc);
}

// now it will be visible in both functions
var $note = $('#note');

$(function () {
    hey("habi");
});
```

Comment: This won't work because #note is most likely not loaded in the DOM yet

Comment: @Jnatalzia - Look at the fiddle carefully. The whole thing is inside an onload handler.

Comment: @Jnatalzia If you look at the fiddle you'll see the onLoad event being specified...

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the $note variable is limited to that document.ready() function. You need to move it outside the `$(function () etc...` in order to have it scoped correctly. Then you can assign it in that function.

```
var $note;    

$(function () {
    $note =  $('#note');
    hey("habi");
});
```

Comment: For the record, though - global scope for variables isn't recommended.  It would be better to move `function hey()` inside the dom ready function

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the variable scope global, use this:

```
var $note;

function hey(kc) {
    $note.html(kc);
}

$(function () {
     $note = $('#note');    
     hey("habi");
});
```